# Rate Over Distance Particle System Not Showing - 2D Gameplay

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have bought a particle system pack from the Asset Store of Unity:
[Epic Toon FX](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/vfx/particles/epic-toon-fx-57772)

Now within my project, I want to use object trail effects for my player spaceship.
So I have added my selected particle system object within the child of player spaceship object.
But I can't able to see any trail when I run my project within Unity editor.

Within the particle system, I have noticed that the emission rate is based on distance.
[image]

How to emission this particle system? 
That is big question in the mind.
At present, its parent spaceship object is moving.

Answer (score 0):

Your space ship game object must be having a kinematic rigidbody. The problem with rate over distance is that they are not good to go with kinamatic rigidbody. Try setting the type of rigidbody to dynamic with gravity scale to 0. This should help .

Moreover, remember to move the rigidbody by changing its velocity and not the transform. Also set the simulation space to world.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1291623/particles-rate-over-distance-emission-not-working.html

@Siddharth

Comment: Already my spaceship has dynamic rigidbody and I was using transform to move the spaceship. Now, what do you suggest?

Comment: Your answer did not work for me but within the linked post, whichever answer exists that worked for me. Please cover that point within your answer too so I can mark this as correct answer.

Comment: Done correction. Think it would make the answer more useful for others.

Comment: You have written a reverse line about transform and velocity in your answer.